# laravel :search form where '<='

Tags: laravel

when I use 'like' it works , but whene I use '<=' it dosen'T WORK

```
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $adultes=$request->get('adultes');


         $dispos=   Disponible::where('adultes', '<=','%'.$adultes. '%' )
         ->paginate(5);

        return view('rooms_dispo',['dispos'=>$dispos]);

    }
```

Comment: `'%'.$adultes. '%'` should be  just `$adultes`

Comment: it works ; thnx sir :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $adultes = $request->get('adultes');
    $dispos = Disponible::where('adultes', '<=', $adultes)->paginate(5);
    return view('rooms_dispo', ['dispos' => $dispos]);

 }
```

Comment: You should explain what the issue was and how this fixes it